# jquery, how to get row index taking into account only certain <tr>, not all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

PROBLEM: I want to get the row index of only the rows where there is an "AC" button.  Why? cause i need the dynamically added comment input to match the index i receive in the POST.

Here is my code:

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>
<table id="items" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
        <th width="2%">AC</th>
        <th width="15%">Codigo</th>
        <th width="38%">Articulo</th>
        <th width="15%">Precio</th>
        <th width="15%">Cantidad</th>
        <th width="15%">Total</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-success addrow" type="button">AC</button></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="items[code][]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="items[name][]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="items[price][]" readonly="readonly" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="items[quantity][]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="items[total][]" readonly="readonly" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">-  eliminar</button>
<button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Agregar</button>

    </div>
```

And here is the script:

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
html = '<tr>';
html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
html += '<td><button class="btn btn-success addrow" type="button" id="addrow_'+i+'">AC</button></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="items[code][]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="items[name][]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text"  name="items[price][]" readonly="readonly" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text"  name="items[quantity][]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text"  name="items[total][]" readonly="readonly" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '</tr>';
$('#items').append(html);
i++;
});


$(document).on("click", '.addrow', function (){
var count =  $(this).parent().parent().index();
newrow = '<tr><td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td><td colspan="7"><input type="text" name="items[comment]['+count+']" class="form-control"></td></tr>';
$(this).parent().parent().after(newrow); 
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ejw1h68/

My problem is here I believe: var count =  $(this).parent().parent().index();

If i add the new items and "THEN" add the "AC" everything works fine, i get the same indexes in my POST request, but if i add an item and then the comment and so on, the indexes wont match the comments.

How can i fix this?

Edit: Clarification:
When I submit the form, I get a post request with an array of items, each array has an index that matches the index of the table, my problem is that some items may or may not have a comment.

It works if i add the items and comments in order if i add 4 items first and then to the second item i add a comment i will get this in my POST:

```
[comment] => Array
            (
                [1] => this is a comment, and it should be index 1
            )
```

But, if I for example, add an item then a comment, then a comment, then and item and so on, for the comment of the second item this is what i get:

```
[comment] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [2] => this is a comment, and it should be index 1
                [4] => 
            )
```

As you can see, the second time, when i added the comments var count =  $(this).parent().parent().index(); counted the comments rows towards the total index count, how can i prevent this? or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you just count the number of AC buttons instead of trs with AC buttons?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour, No, every item MUST have an AC button, but no every items has a comment.

Comment: Problem is not clear at all. What post?

Comment: Why don't you just make a variable that counts the number of rows and then each time the buttons are pressed is incremented or decremented?

Comment: @charlietfl I edited the question clarifying my problem.

Comment: @raysn0w. I'm still confused on what you are trying to achieve, but see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/1ejw1h68/2/) - is this what you are expecting (writing index in console.log)?

Comment: @Taleeb No, i used firebug to the this: '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[comment][2]">' the second comment should be index 1 not 2.

Comment: This is a very poor way to keep track. Use unique identifiers for rows based on db id and return the parent id along with each comment

Comment: @charlietfl How can i do that? would you care to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my example which could give you an idea for your problem**

```js
//To add Dynamic Row for product    
$("#add").click(function() {

  var row = $("#consumptionTable tbody>tr:last").last().clone();     
  var oldId = Number(row.attr('id').slice(-1));     
  var id = 1 + oldId;

  row.attr('id', 'rowformat_' + id );
  row.find('#product_' + oldId).attr('id', 'product_' + id);
  row.find('#quantity_' + oldId).attr('id', 'quantity_' + id);
  row.find('#unit_' + oldId).attr('id', 'unit_' + id);
  row.find('#errText_' + oldId).attr('id', 'errText_' + id);
  $('#consumptionTable').append(row);
  $('#quantity_' + id).val(""); //To clear value from cloned input

});
 
//To Remove the Dynamic Row
$("#remove").click(function() { 
  var rowCount = $('#consumptionTable tbody tr').length;  
  if(rowCount >1){
    $( "#consumptionTable tbody> tr:last" ).remove();
  }else{
    alert("Cannot Remove anymore Row")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Consumption_Detail">Consumption Detail:  
      <input type="button"  class="dynamicBtn" id="add" value="Add Row" /> 
      <input type="button"  class="dynamicBtn" id="remove" value="Remove Row" />
    </label>   
    <div class="table-responsive" >
      <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="consumptionTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>          
            <th>Product <sup>*</sup></th>
            <th>Quantity <sup>*</sup></th>
            <th>Unit</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="addTbody">

          <tr id="rowformat_0">
            <td width="16%">
              <select id="product_0">
                <option value="">Select</option>
              </select>
            </td>

            <td width="4%">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="quantity_0" />
            </td>

            <td width="4%">
              <select  id="unit_0" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @raysn0w **Good to hear**

Answer (score 0):

Im answering my question cause i realize that what i want to do, in my case, is not the right way.

Why?.- Cause i was manually adding the indexes of my comments inputs and creating another problem in that step. what would had happen if the user deletes a row of items above the comment? the comments wouldnt match the items anymore.

Here is what i did: i created the comments input boxed dynamically along the items and hide them using 'Modal Boxes' in the same row, this way i solved all my problems in one step.

Code:

```
<table id="items" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
    <th width="2%" style="text-align: center">AC</th>
    <th width="15%">Codigo</th>
    <th width="38%">Articulo</th>
    <th width="15%">Precio</th>
    <th width="15%">Cantidad</th>
    <th width="15%">Total</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button">AC</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="items[code][]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="items[name][]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="items[price][]" readonly="readonly" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="items[quantity][]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" name="items[total][]" readonly="readonly" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar comentario</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" name="items[comment][]" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Eliminar</button>
<button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Agregar</button>
```

Script:

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
html = '<tr>';
html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
html += '<td><button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_'+i+'" type="button">AC</button></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="items[code][]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="items[name][]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text"  name="items[price][]" readonly="readonly" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text"  name="items[quantity][]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td>';
html += '<input type="text"  name="items[total][]" readonly="readonly" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">';
html += '<div id="myModal_'+i+'" class="modal fade" role="dialog">';
html += '<div class="modal-dialog">';
html += '<div class="modal-content">';
html += '<div class="modal-header">';
html += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';
html += '<h4 class="modal-title">Agregar comentario</h4>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="modal-body">';
html += '<input type="text" name="items[comment][]" class="form-control">';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="modal-footer">';
html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
html += '</div></div></div></div>';
html += '</td>';
html += '</tr>';
$('#items').append(html);
i++;
});
```

and here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fu39najg/

I hope this may help someone in the same position as i was.